# Cannot find `hw ether` to force MAC address change

Tags: networking, raspbian-stretch, ethernet

This is a follow up question to [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89904/why-isnt-my-forced-mac-address-change-working/90006#90006) and subsequently [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89994/failed-to-create-symbolic-link/90003#90003).

To save you from a long read I am trying to force a MAC address change on my Pi Zero ethernet adapter with:

`ifconfig eth0 down; ifconfig eth0 hw ether 21:21:21:21:00:11; ifconfig eth0 up; ifconfig eth0`

But I receive the error message:

```
ether: Host name lookup failure
ifconfig: `--help' gives usage information.
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::bb7e:8c36:1a6c:4d5e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 10:10:12:10:10:10  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1342  bytes 95363 (93.1 KiB)
        RX errors 1  dropped 5  overruns 0  frame 1
        TX packets 817  bytes 102452 (100.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Why can I not find `ether`? Many additional details leading up to this point can be found in the linked questions if needed.

Comment: odd error - the 21:21:21:21:00:11 address in the question is not valid - because of the LSB set in the first byte of the MAC ... but I can see the MAC is 10:10:12:10:10:10 in the output - are you actually trying to set the address to 21:21:21:21:00:11? In a previous answer I suggested the safest MAC addresses https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88936/33057 the first part being x2, x6, xA or xE

Comment: Yeah I was trying to switch it to another address just to test the method again and happened to pick 21 arbitrarily. I also tried a MAC address starting with 99, is that also invalid?

Comment: My mistake I should have followed your initial advice.

Comment: any ODD number as the second digit i.e. `1`,`3`,`5`,`7`,`9`,`B`,`D`,`F` will be invalid ... the `2`,`6`,`A`,`E` in the list are the so called "locally administered" MAC addresses - not likely to clash with a manufacturer MAC address (whose second digits would be one of `0`,`4`,`8`,`C`

Comment: @JaromandaX even using `22:12:12:12:12:12` I receive the exact same error message

Comment: @JaromandaX The other options you mentioned have the same error too

Comment: really? I though you said [in this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84419/discussion-on-question-by-matt-why-isnt-my-forced-mac-address-change-working) that `ifconfig eth0 down; ifconfig eth0 hw ether 10:00:00:00:00:11; ifconfig eth0 up; ifconfig eth0` worked? and from the output in the question `ether 10:10:12:10:10:10` looks like it does

Comment: `ether: Host name lookup failure` - that's a weird error to get ... type those commands one at a time ... it's definitely the `ifconfig eth0 hw ether ......` line that triggers that error?

Comment: @JaromandaX to your first comment, that is correct. Which is why this is so weird, the command was previously working perfectly fine and suddenly it stopped working

Comment: Figured it out.... This is embarassing, I'd forgotten to write `eth0` in one of the commands

Comment: Please make an answer and accept it two days later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten an `eth0` in `ifconfig eth0 down; ifconfig eth0 hw ether 21:21:21:21:00:11; ifconfig eth0 up; ifconfig eth0`

Additionally, as Jaromanda said - 21:21:21:21:00:11 is an invalid MAC address. The second digit of the MAC address ought to be `2`, `6`, `A`, or `E`, the locally administered addresses.